How should I think about this model
I have been learning the control system tools in Mathematica, and recently exploring the Microcontroller Kit. I have run into a use of NonlinearStateSpaceModel which I don't understand.
The use occurs in the Microcontroller Kit Tutorial in the first section: "Setting up your machine." In that section there is a model which is intended to toggle the LED on the Arduino board with each sampling period.
When I try to obtain an OutputResponse from this model I get an empty list. Is this model a construct which is useful only for work with microcontrollers? Or should it deliver an output in the usual way, but I'm just doing it wrong? What is the best way to think about this model?
(*NonlinearStateSpace model from MicrocontollerKit example*)
nlsm = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{Which[x > 0, 0, True, 
      1]}, {x}}, {x}, {}, {Automatic}, Automatic, SamplingPeriod -> 1];

(* I thought this would produce alternating 1s and 0s*)
OutputResponse[{nlsm, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}]

(* {} *)


Change the model to nlsm = NonlinearStateSpaceModel[{{Which[x > 0, 0, True,       1]}, {x}}, {x}, {u}, {Automatic}, Automatic, SamplingPeriod -> 1]. Otherwise, OutputResponse sees it as a model with no inputs.

Thank you, @Suba Thomas.  Of course.
